# optimize code to add css class to parent div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a class to the parent div which is `<div class="form-group">` i got it to work, but was wondering if there was a shorter or simpler way to do so? Here is my 2 HTML situations

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label required" for="Comment_postcode">Your Postcode <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-9 error">
        <span style="position: relative; display: inline-block;" class="twitter-typeahead">
            <input style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border-color: transparent; box-shadow: none; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255);" class="tt-hint" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="off" disabled="" type="text"/>
            <input dir="auto" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top;" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" class="form-control tt-query" name="Comment[postcode]" id="Comment_postcode" type="text"/>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label required" for="Comment_purchased">This vehicle was purchased <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>      
    <div class="col-md-9 error">
        <select id="Comment_purchased" class="form-control input-md">
            <option value="">Select One</option>
            <option value="1">New</option>
            <option value="2">Used</option>
        </select>
        <div class="errorMessage" id="Comment_purchased_em_" style="display:none">Purchased cannot be blank.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my JQuery code to add or remove the has-error class

```
if (i != "Comment_postcode") {
    $("#"+i).parent("div").parent("div").addClass("has-error");
} else {
    $("#"+i).parent("span").parent("div").parent("div").addClass("has-error");
}
```

how would i optimize the code above? if possible without the if-else statement. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **[closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** to get closest parent

```
 $("#"+i).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
```

> **Description:** For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing
>   up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

you also can use **[parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)**

```
$("#"+i).parents(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
```

Comment: what if the parent `div` element with class `.form-group` wrapped inside of another one `div` element with the same class.? At that situation your code would add class to the both. atleast use `.first()` before using the `.addClass()` function. Anyway using `.closest()` would be the best choice here.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy yeah, but in the question, I don't think that's happening! so it makes this answer to work on this case

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy also, I'm not saying anyone should do it, but it would solve the issue `$("#"+i).parents(".form-group:last").addClass("has-error");` (in case someone insists using this method!) :D